# How to use a pom file in the Maven deployer plugin for Gradle?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I need to be able to generate a pom file locally and deploy the project to sonatype.

Here is how I am doing so:

```
task createPom {
    doLast {
        pom.project {
            groupId = "com.example"
            //...
        }.writeTo("pom.xml")
    }
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            beforeDeployment { MavenDeployment deployment -> signing.signPom(deployment) }

            repository(url: "https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/") {
                authentication(userName: ossrhUsername, password: ossrhPassword)
            }

            snapshotRepository(url: "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/") {
                authentication(userName: ossrhUsername, password: ossrhPassword)
            }

            pom.project {
                groupId = "com.example"
                //...
            }

        }
    }
}
```

As you noticed it doesn't follow the DRY principle as I am writing the same pom file two times. If I need to add or remove any field in the POM file I need to remove it in both places.
I have an idea. We can say that the `uploadArchives` task depends on the `createPom` task like this `uploadArchives (dependsOn: createPom)`. Now we could generate a POM file and then read when use `mavenDeployer`. But how to tell `mavenDeployer` to read pom from the file and not generate default pom file? Or if it is possible to generate global pom variable and use it in both tasks.